# Android, key -> value structure stored safely, not modifiable

Tags: android, collections, storage, hashtable

I’d like to store a key->value structure of data e.g.

```
2354235 => string1
3453453 => string2
```

The structure has to be defined at build time and not modifiable over the runtime (security reasons). It must be stored securely (readable only by the app). Storing that in source code and in sqlite db are not acceptable. Any other ideas?

Comment: if you are not going to store it in app or in database, then where you will store?

Comment: there isnt any "secure" place to store data on a device. Anything stored on a device should never be considered secure because you can always get at it some way. create a JSON output string and encode it then write it to a file. thats somewhat secure but not really

Comment: What kind of app are you developing? Use encrypted SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking two things:

1) Where can you store that at build time, outside of code or DB.
2) How can you make it only readable by the app.

For 1), I suggest you just use an encrypted `raw` file (place it in `/res/raw`). They cannot be modified, and it could be just CSV or JSON. Check the [javax.crypto](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) package for the necessary classes for encription.

For 2), it depends on how secure you want it to be. You could download the decryption key from a server using a secure connection, but then you need to be sure that what's connecting to the server is really your app. You can use something like what's described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) for validating your app in the server:

> **Summary**
>
> Doing this is a multi-step process, which I’ll outline in full, but here’s the short version: You use the GoogleAuthUtil class, available through Google Play services, to retrieve a string called an “ID Token”. You send the token to your back end and your back end can use it to quickly and cheaply verify which app sent it and who was using the app.